# I am trying to store twitter trends into a text file but getting errors before storing into a .txt file

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-twitter

```
my_trends = api.GetTrendsWoeid(my_woe_id)
trends = json.loads(my_trends)
```

but I get error :  raise

```
TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

. I am using python 3.7. and python-twitter. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging such errors is part of the fun - how to do it?

First step: use python to inspect the thing that makes problems:

```
print(type(my_trends))       # will tell you it is a list
print(*my_trends)            # prints all list elements wich tells you what they are
```

then look into the API for what you are using:  [twitter.api.Api.GetTrendsWoeid](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html#twitter.api.Api.GetTrendsWoeid) which would tell you, that:

[image: documentation thats shows the used method returns a list]

which fully explains why you get

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not **list.**

Comment: thanks, you are right it is a list, so how to load it into json as understand that it only accept string, I tried to use my_trends = str(api.GetTrendsWoeid(my_woe_id)) to convert it to string but I get :raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: @Mohamm Check what the items you get returned are - maybe they are strings that can be parsed. If not - you probably do not need to json at all because the API you  are using does this already internally and returns fully fledged python objects. I havent used this API - so I cant say. Please research the stuff you are using.